# Debugging In SQLDeveloper over SSH Tunnel

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using SQL Developer over an SSH tunnel to my database server without any problems.  However, it fails when I try to use the debugger.  The debugging window shows:

```
Executing PL/SQL: CALL DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.CONNECT_TCP( '10.72.227.252', '52413' )
```

But then I get the errors:

```
ORA-30683: failure establishing connection to debugger
ORA-12535: TNS:operation timed out
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP", line 68
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Is there a special listener that has to be running on the database server in order to debug over the network? It looks like the CONNECT_TCP call is trying to connect to a different port (52413 in the above example) every time I run it.  How do I debug in SQL Developer over an SSH tunnel?

Comment: Not something I've tried (yet); [this post](http://www.packtpub.com/article/debugging-pl-sql-in-oracle-sql-developer) has quite a lot of info, including about remote debugging. I suspect you need to restrict (or prompt) for the port and have that tunnelled? Not in a position to try it right now.

Answer (score 0):

The oerr command shows this for the `ORA-30683` error:

> ORA-30683: failure establishing connection to debugger

`Cause:` An error was indicated when trying to establish a connection to a debugger. Usually a TNS error will display along with this message to further explain the problem, although this TNS error will likely be hidden if you choose to trap the error. In your case you also get the ORA-12535 operation timed out error.

`Action:` Correct the indicated parameter value and try again.

For details [check here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_30683_failure_establishing_connection_to_debugger.htm)

Comment: Yes, I already saw this posting.  The problem is that I am trying to connect via an SSH tunnel.  This doesn't answer my question though.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
Solution
```

SQL> grant debug connect session, debug any procedure to

Answer (score 0):

Well experienced same problem, try these solutions:

1- Grant debug connect session to urUser;
   Grant Debug any procedure to urUser;

2 - Tools -> preferences -> debugger and mark ask host for debugging...

3- when you compile be sure to give the ip adress with which ur machine on where sql developper is running, if it still doesnt work, try to turn off the firewall and retest it.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary solution: switch debugger from jdwp to old version.
Add at the end of the ***ide.properties***:

```
DatabaseDebuggerDisableJDWP=true
```

This file location:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system${VERSION}\o.sqldeveloper.${SYSTEM_VERSION}
```